# Modification Braintree cardForm with Card.io numbers Android

Tags: android, braintree, card.io

I use the cardForm class (BrainTree SDK) and I would like to inject card.io result when the scan is succeded in the cardFormView but the member variable is private (mcardNumber).

The source code is compiled in bytecode

Do you have any solutions ? Thank's for advance.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == MY_SCAN_REQUEST_CODE) {
        String resultDisplayStr;
        if (data != null && data.hasExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SCAN_RESULT)) {
            CreditCard scanResult = data.getParcelableExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SCAN_RESULT);

            // Never log a raw card number. Avoid displaying it, but if necessary use getFormattedCardNumber()
            resultDisplayStr = "Card Number: " + scanResult.getRedactedCardNumber() + "\n";

            mCardForm.mCardNumber.setText(scanResult.getRedactedCardNumber()); // Access Error

            if (scanResult.isExpiryValid()) {
                resultDisplayStr += "Expiration Date: " + scanResult.expiryMonth + "/" + scanResult.expiryYear + "\n";
            }
            Log.e("OK","---> " + resultDisplayStr);
        }
        else {
            resultDisplayStr = "Scan was canceled.";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The Braintree card form is in a separate repo... Are you looking for [this source](https://github.com/braintree/android-card-form)?

Comment: Thank's a lot, I redefined the cardForm class and put the member variable in public access ;)

Comment: Hi Scoriop , Can you please suggest where you add page CardForm , I have the same problem .